# Help convert Apache rewrite rules to PHP regular expressions

Tags: regex

Short story: I am using this technique to auto-version my css and js files by adding a string to the filename with filemtime():
http://w-shadow.com/blog/2012/07/30/automatic-versioning-of-css-js/

I got it up and running perfectly on my local machine (MAMP), but I use WP Engine for my hosting and they are set up on nginx and don't support .htaccess rewrite rules.

They do have a place to enter PHP regular expressions (preg_replace), though, and their instructions look like this:

> HTML Post-Processing
>   A mapping of PHP regular expressions to replacement values which are executed on all blog HTML after WordPress finishes emitting the entire page. The pattern and replacement behavior is in the manner of preg_replace().
>
> The following example removes all HTML comments in the first pattern, and causes a favicon (with any filename extension) to be loaded from another domain in the second pattern:
>
> `#<!--.*?-->#s =>`
>
> `#\bsrc="/(favicon\..*)"# => src="http://mycdn.somewhere.com/$1"`

. So I'm wondering how hard it is to convert this rewrite rule to a PHP regular expression:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]`

And if this would even be doing the same thing as the apache rewrite. the whole point of the technique is to bust the browser cache for css or js files and time they are changed, but without resorting to query strings, which have various drawbacks.

Comment: Suggest migration to ServerFault or StackOverflow -- question is out of scope for this site, as per the FAQ: "we do not handle questions: not specific to WordPress (even if they happen in its context)"

Comment: I understand this rule, but I don't think it should be interpreted as: if you ask something that is about a specific WordPress issue but could also apply to other technologies, then it doesn't belong here.

Everything about my question pertains to WordPress. The fact that WordPress runs on servers that use technology that other systems also use shouldn't make my question off topic, IMO.

Comment: The recommended rule of a thumb to check if your question is truly WP-specific is - _does question stay same if you completely remove WP from it?_ And this one does. There is nothing WP specific about that Apache rewrite or PHP regexp you want to convert it to. Please understand that [site's scope as per FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) exist to discourage off-topic, but also to make sure you ask in place where you are likely to get best answers. In this case it's likely StackOverflow or ServerFault as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's pretty much the same.  Take your regex, delimit it, drop it in a string and escape the right things, then take your rewrite rule and use single quotes to make it a string, and you're done.  In your example:

```
$newUrl = preg_replace('/^(.*)\\.[\\d]{10}\\.(css|js)$/', '$1.$2', $url);
```

This will properly rewrite anything url you give it.  However, it sounds like these preg_replaces are being done across a large document, which means your regex there won't do what you think it will.  That, however, is a completely separate question.  One I won't even guess at, because I don't know what your requirements are.  If you need help crafting the regex, please open another question with your specific requirements.

Also:  Next time, [Check the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Thank you for the help. All I'm really trying to do is remove a 10 digit string of numbers between two periods from urls that end on .css or .js

I don't know if/how it would differ to do with this way vs the rewrite. When I have the rewrite working on my local machine the digits are there in the source, but the request goes to the correct file anyway, even thou the digit are not actually in the file name.

The point of doing this to bust the browser cache when updating css/js files, without resorting to query strings, so I don't know if the preg_replace method would negate this effect.

Comment: I also see in the hosting documentation of this feature that the regex needs to be in this kind of format: `#\bsrc="/(favicon\..*)"# => src="http://mycdn.somewhere.com/$1"`